# Not able to View PushViewController in Xamarin.IOS

Tags: xamarin, uiwebview, xamarin.ios

I have two `ViewControllers` in the `First ViewController` just having the buttons on this button `touchupinside` event I am trying to open the `Second ViewController`. This Second ViewController is having the `webView`. From `touchupinside` I am passing the url. But here I'm not able to see the `Second ViewController` and also not able to see the webView.

In the UI button => drag the `Action Segue(Show)`.

`FirstViewController` Code:

```cs
UINavigationController _nav = null;
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    _nav = new UINavigationController();
}
partial Void BtnOne_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
{
    _nav.PushViewController(new CustomeWebViewController("http://www.google.com"), true);
}
```

`SecondViewController` Code:

```cs
string _url;
public CustomeWebViewController(string url)
{
    _url = url;
}
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    var webView = new UIWebView(View.Bounds);
    webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(_url)));
    webView.ScalesPageToFit = true;
    View.AddSubview(webView);
}
```

Comment: Hello, I replicated your code, and tested if. I fixed the problem as you can see in my answer. Hope you mark my answer as correct thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that you don't have a valid `NavigationController`. And you must have one to navigate.

The first thing that must be done is to add a `NavigationController` to your `Storyboard`.

To do this, follow [instructions](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/hello,_iOS_multiscreen/hello,_iOS_multiscreen_quickstart/) 3, 4, 5, 6 e 7.

But basically you will add a `NavigationController`, and make it point your `FirstViewController`.

Now add make the `FirstViewController` point to the `SecondViewController`

In the code of your `FirstViewController` you must do this:

```cs
partial void BtnOne_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
{
    NavigationController.PushViewController(new secondviewcontrller("https://xamarin.com"), true);
}
```

Result:

[image]
[image]

---

### Alternative

---

Note: Its a better practice to instantiate your `ViewControllers` from `Storyboard` so you could do this instead:

```cs
partial void BtnOne_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
{

    var other = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("secondviewcontroller") as secondviewcontrller;
    other.SetUrl("https://xamarin.com");

    NavigationController.PushViewController(other, true);
}
```

And then in your `SecondViewContrller`:

```cs
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    webView = new UIWebView(View.Bounds);
    View.AddSubview(webView);
    webView.ScalesPageToFit = true;
    webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(_url)));
}

public void SetUrl(string url) 
    _url = url;
}
```

Comment: in your first approach do i need to add Control of UIWebView in secondViewController. because I used the same code for that u post in "Alternative" to display webpage.

Comment: I added the UIWebview programmatically in both scenarios.